# Trust Relationship between workstation and primary domain failed

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003

I have a pc on windows 7 and windows server 2003.

This is the only pc that has this problem. i know how to reattach back the domain to the pc , and i have to use local administrator account to do that.

But here's the catch. The Local Administrator account was disabled by the previous IT Supervisor.

Is there any workaround that i could use?

Steps i've tried :

1.Going to Server Manager and reset the PC account.

2.Tried to login to local Administrator without the Domain name infront.

Comment: Best thing to do, if authorized by your job and allowed to, is create a USB DOS Boot drive (such as RMPrepUSB) and reset the Local Administrator Password. This link should assist - http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/12---bootable-usb-drive-to-reset-windows-user-pasword -

Comment: if by resetting the local admin password , would the account be re-enabled?

Comment: Correct - resetting the password to the admin account will allow you to login as the Local Administrator. You can then create a new password for this account or leave it blank

Comment: Is this the same method with Hiren Boot?

Comment: Yes - Any DOS boot where you can access profile registry files will allow you to reset a user account

Comment: @MikeDiglio - THX MAN! IT WORKS! XD Lifesaver!

Comment: @MikeDiglio You should write your comments up as an answer ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill I have gone ahead and made it the answer :)

Comment: @MikeDiglio Hopefully the OP will come back and give you the big green tick ;)

Comment: i just did.. :) thx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is the best way to solve the OP's problems:

Using a DOS application, such as Hirens or RMPrepUSB) you will be able to access the user profile registry list. From here, you are able to reset a local administrator account and clear the password. After a reboot, you will then be able to log into this administrator account.

Instructions to do this with RMPrepUSB is at the following link:

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/12---bootable-usb-drive-to-reset-windows-user-pasword

Answer (score 0):

You can skip removing and re-adding the PC to the domain with the following PowerShell command:

```
Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Credential example.com\admin -Repair
```

If you can log in as a user (non-admin), open a powershell console and type in that command. Change `example.com\admin` to the name of a domain admin account (and enter the username and password).

Normally I run this as a local admin and I honestly don't know if it will work when run as a regular user, but it's worth a try.

*Note: Running this command means no need for a reboot, so it's handy for quickly fixing these trust relationships.*

Comment: Dear Sir , i could not even login to the PC as even the local admin or local user account has been disabled by the previous IT.